# How do I add multiple commits in SVN into one Post-Commit HOOK?

Tags: svn, email, notifications, post-commit

I have successfully implemented the post-commit email notification for the post-commit hook. Now I'm looking at a bigger problem, I don't want the hook to send email for every commit. Is there a way to use the hook to maybe write the content of the email to a text file and maybe use another hook or something to send the text file?

I basically wnat to send an email with information of multiple commits.

thanks,
Oded.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to decide *when* you actually want to send the email:

1. Every tenth commit?
2. At midnight?
3. When tagging?

Then you should be able to easily implement a scheme working as you need it:

1. in the post-commit hook: only send an email when `revision number % 10 == 0`
2. create a cron job
3. in the post-commit hook: detect when creating a tag

You can use `svn log` and `svn diff` with the `-r FROM:TO` option to gather the needed information by date or revision numbers. See [the svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html) for more infos.

Comment: The email I want to send need to contain all the information of all the commits... not the 5th or the 10th....

Comment: So write the contents out to a file on every commit and send the file on the 10th commit.

Comment: Or use "svn log" and "svn diff" to get to the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the post-commit email sender script to send an email after some commits (e.g. the revision number is a multiple of 5)

To help write the script, you may use svnlook to fetch previous revision logs.

Here's part of a Python script I wrote to send SMS to developers:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, urllib, os
from subprocess import *

repo = sys.argv[2]
rev = sys.argv[3]

cmdlog = 'svnlook log -r %s %s'%(rev, repo)
cmdauthor = 'svnlook author -r %s %s'%(rev, repo)
log = Popen(cmdlog, stdout=PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read().strip()
author = Popen(cmdauthor, stdout=PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read().strip()
```

And in the post-commit file

```
#!/bin/bash

export LANG=en_US.utf8
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

./sms.py commit $REPOS $REV
```

You can refer to this example to fetch log information from svn repository by the command **svnlook**